# Activation gradient penalty

Tags: pytorch, autograd

Here's a simple neural network, where I’m trying to penalize the norm of activation gradients:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 32, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(64 * 5 * 5, 10)

    def forward(self, input):
        conv1 = self.conv1(input)
        pool1 = self.pool(conv1)
        self.relu1 = self.relu(pool1)
        self.relu1.retain_grad()
        conv2 = self.conv2(relu1)
        pool2 = self.pool(conv2)
        relu2 = self.relu(pool2)
        self.relu2 = relu2.view(relu2.size(0), -1)
        self.relu2.retain_grad()
        return self.linear(relu2)

model = Net()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

for i in range(1000):
    output = model(input)
    loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(output, label)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward(retain_graph=True)

    grads = torch.autograd.grad(loss, [model.relu1, model.relu2], create_graph=True)

    grad_norm = 0
    for grad in grads:
        grad_norm += grad.pow(2).sum()

    grad_norm.backward()

    optimizer.step()
```

However, it does not produce the desired regularization effect. If I do the same thing for weights (instead of activations), it works well. Am I doing this right (in terms of pytorch machinery)? Specifically, what happens in grad_norm.backward() call? I just want to make sure the weight gradients are updated, and not activation gradients. Currently, when I print out gradients for weights and activations immediately before and after that line, both change - so I’m not sure what’s going on.

Comment: What do you mean by "activation gradients"?

Comment: @ChrisHolland, gradients of the loss function with respect to activations (self.relu1 and self.relu2). I want to penalize their growth.

Comment: ReLU does not have any trainable parameters so there is no gradient

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Why would they need to be trainable to have gradients? How could the error be backpropagated through them if they didn't have gradients?

Comment: What you are doing here is to start a second optimization process to optimize for the gradient norm, which computes higher order gradients. This means that you are changing your parameters to produce gradients that are getting smaller and smaller - the gradients, _not the weights_. Besides, it may produce unforeseen consequences, as I'm not sure that the second optimization process does not interfere with the "main" one. So are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: The goal is to make the model resistant to activation distortions (e.g. adding gaussian noise). One well known approach is to apply weight gradient penalty, and it works ok when implemented in this manner. I want to do the same for activations. Do you have any thoughts on this potential optimization interference or any other issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code ends up computing some of the gradients twice in each step. I also suspect it actually never zeroes out the activation gradients, so they accumulate across steps.

In general:

- `x.backward()` computes gradient of `x` wrt. computation graph leaves (e.g. weight tensors and other variables), as well as wrt. nodes explicitly marked with `retain_grad()`. It accumulates the computed gradient in tensors' `.grad` attributes.
- `autograd.grad(x, [y, z])` returns gradient of `x` wrt. `y` and `z` regardless of whether they would normally retain grad or not. By default, it will *also* accumulate gradient in all leaves' `.grad` attributes. You can prevent this by passing `only_inputs=True`.

I prefer to use `backward()` only for the optimization step, and `autograd.grad()` whenever my goal is to obtain "reified" gradients as intermediate values for another computation. This way, I can be sure that no unwanted gradients remain lying around in tensors' `.grad` attributes after I'm done with them.

```python
import torch
from torch import nn
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 32, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(64 * 5 * 5, 10)

    def forward(self, input):
        conv1 = self.conv1(input)
        pool1 = self.pool(conv1)
        self.relu1 = self.relu(pool1)
        conv2 = self.conv2(self.relu1)
        pool2 = self.pool(conv2)
        self.relu2 = self.relu(pool2)
        relu2 = self.relu2.view(self.relu2.size(0), -1)
        return self.linear(relu2)


model = Net()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
grad_penalty_weight = 10.

for i in range(1000000):
    # Random input and labels; we're not really learning anything
    input = torch.rand(1, 3, 32, 32)
    label = torch.randint(0, 10, (1,))

    output = model(input)
    loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(output, label)

    # This is where the activation gradients are computed
    # only_inputs is optional here, since we're going to call optimizer.zero_grad() later
    # But it makes clear that we're *only* interested in the activation gradients at this point
    grads = torch.autograd.grad(loss, [model.relu1, model.relu2], create_graph=True, only_inputs=True)

    grad_norm = 0
    for grad in grads:
        grad_norm += grad.pow(2).sum()

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss = loss + grad_norm * grad_penalty_weight
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

This code *appears* to work, in that the activation gradients do get smaller.
I cannot comment on the viability of this technique as a regularization method.

Comment: Thank you, and I apologize for not replying sooner. Very good point about `only_inputs` parameter. I don't quite understand why do you think the gradients are not zeroed out - I do use `optimizer.zero_grad()` in my code. Can you please explain?

Comment: If memory serves, `optimizer.zero_grad()` zeroes out only the gradients of variables specified at the time of `optimizer`'s construction, in this case `model.parameters()`., I'm not sure what exactly your code ends up doing as a result. Half an hour with a debugger might clear it up.